# ndk-build option NDK_APP_APPLICATION_MK not working?

Tags: android, android-ndk

I am trying to pass a preprocessor define into my native code using the Android NDK that is dependent on build configuration. This is so that I can disable some debug native code easily by switching build configuration in eclipse.

As I understand it, preprocessor defines are added in the android.mk file using LOCAL_CFLAGS or to the Application.mk file using APP_CFLAGS, and I have both of these options working.

So, I am trying to use the ndk-build option NDK_APP_APPLICATION_MK to specify a different Application.mk in one build configuration as follows:

```
ndk-build NDK_APP_APPLICATION_MK=jni/ApplicationDistribution.mk
```

This is documented to behave as follows:

```
ndk-build NDK_APP_APPLICATION_MK=<file>
--> rebuild, using a specific Application.mk pointed to by
    the NDK_APP_APPLICATION_MK command-line variable.
```

This generates the following log:

```
Android NDK: Parsing xxx/jni/Application.mk
```

which suggests that it is still looking for the original Application.mk file.

Is this a known bug? Is there an easier way to pass preprocessor defines to native code only for certain eclipse build configurations?

thank you for your time.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Documentation is wrong here - misspelled option.
Use `NDK_APPLICATION_MK` instead of `NDK_APP_APPLICATION_MK`.